# Change the textcolor of listview selected by user other are textview color are set to default in android

Tags: android, listview

in my android app user select only one item in listview and that particular item textview color are changed. if user select other item in list view previous item color are set to default 
 i used the following method to reset all textview color when user select but when scrolling random text color are changed please if you have any other solution to solve this problem

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
```

but getchildcount method return only currently display item textview :-(

```
                for(int i=0;i<lv.getChildCount();i++)
                {
                    Log.i("text",((TextView)((LinearLayout)lv.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber)).getText()+"");
            ((TextView)((LinearLayout)lv.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber)).setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
                }
                ((TextView)((LinearLayout)arg1).findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber)).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2a9bc8"));
                changeHeader(0);
                ((LinearLayout)lv.getChildAt(0)).refreshDrawableState();
        }   
    });
```

customAdapter

public class Search_Truck_Number_adapter extends BaseAdapter {

```
private static ArrayList<ListitemDetail> itemDetailarraylist;
private Context context=null;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        ArrayList<TextView> TextViewObjects=new ArrayList<TextView>();
public Search_Truck_Number_adapter(ArrayList<ListitemDetail> result,Context c) {
    itemDetailarraylist=result;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    context=c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemDetailarraylist.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return itemDetailarraylist.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_act_cell,null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber);
        holder.position=position;
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    TextViewObjects.add(holder.txt_itemName);
    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailarraylist.get(position).getName());
    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    TextView txt_itemName;
    Integer position;
}
```

}

Comment: you can use a selector for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because getChildAt() only works for the views in the list that are shown on the screen, you can first call lv.getFirstVisiblePostion() (This is a method of class android.widget.AdapterView which ListView indirectly extends (see ListView in the android developers guide and look at the inheritance tree)), then if you know the index of the view relative to its position on the screen, you can add the index to the result of getFirstVisiblePosition(), eg getFirstVisiblePosition() + index. This will give you the position of the view with respect to the entire list, not just what is shown on the screen. You can use this to change the text color. -- hope this helps

Comment: it's working now i just store the postion of item click and cheack the condition in getView() method.thank you for your response

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Search_Truck_Number_adapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
{
    private Integer no=null;

    private static ArrayList<ListitemDetail> itemDetailarraylist;
    private Context context=null;
            LayoutInflater inflater;
    public Search_Truck_Number_adapter(ArrayList<ListitemDetail> result,Context c) {
        itemDetailarraylist=result;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        context=c;
    }   
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemDetailarraylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return itemDetailarraylist.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_act_cell,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txt_itemName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber);
            holder.position=position;
            convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.position=position;
        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailarraylist.get(position).getName());
        if(no!=null)
        {
        if(no!=position)
        {
            holder.txt_itemName.setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        }
        else
        {
            holder.txt_itemName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2a9bc8"));
        }
        }
        return convertView;
    }

     static class ViewHolder{
        TextView txt_itemName;
        Integer position;
        Integer Select_Position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        SearchActivity sa=new SearchActivity();
        sa.changeHeader(0, context);
      ListView lv=(ListView) v.getParent();
      for(int i=0;i<lv.getChildCount();i++)
      {
         ((TextView)((LinearLayout)lv.getChildAt(i)).findViewById(R.id.TruckNumber)).setTextColor(Color.LTGRAY); 
      }
        no=((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).position;
        ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).txt_itemName.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2a9bc8"));
        Log.i("Position", ((ViewHolder)v.getTag()).position+"");
    }
}
```